# Fill in form data from Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, node-webkit

Excuse my ignorance. I'm just learning how to use node webkit and was wondering how to fill in form data via a menu item. I'm using the code below and filling in the form data with the 'fill' menu item. However it reports that var elem = document.getElementById("username"); returns null. Any ideas?

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var file = require('file.js');
var menu = new gui.Menu({ type: 'menubar' });

menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
    label: 'File',
    submenu: new gui.Menu()
}));

menu.items[0].submenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
    label: 'New',
    click: function () {
        gui.Window.open('index.html');
    }
}));
menu.items[0].submenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
    label: 'fill',
    click: function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("username");
    elem.value = "myusername";
    }
}));

gui.Window.get().menu = menu;
```

The HTML I'm testing this with is just an html document with one input

```
<input type="text" id="username">
```

This is the error I get

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at MenuItem.menu.items.(anonymous function).submenu.append.gui.MenuItem.click (file:///C:/nodewebkit/js/main.js:22:13)
    at MenuItem.handleEvent (menuitem.js:171:12)
    at IDWeakMap.global.__nwObjectsRegistry.handleEvent (node.js:795:26)
```

**UPDATE:**
I don't know if this is relevant but one thing I have noticed is that when I attempt to perform this in the console, i get 'Undefined' when performing

```
 var elem = document.getElementById("username");
```

However when I enter

```
elem = document.getElementById("username");
```

it returns the element just fine. However making that change in the script still leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: All it has in it is <input type="text" id="username">

Comment: Works for me, what version are you using?

Comment: Tripple check your HTML, because it returns null only if there is NO element with ID `username`.

Comment: Looking at it more closely in the developer window I'm getting an error that says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'

Comment: I'm triple checking my html. I'm looking in the developer window and I can clearly see my input with the id 'username'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. weirdly enough, using jquery helped me fix it. I have an html page with an image tag with id "close". If I tried using document.getElementById('close') as is, it would always return null. So I wrapped it inside jquery like this:

```
var nw = require('nw.gui');
var win = nw.Window.get();


$(function(){
    var close = document.getElementById('close');
    close.onclick = function(){
        win.close();
    };
});
```

It started working immediately. Very confused about why nwjs behaves like this.